# Removing an onclick event from a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, conditional-statements, removeeventlistener

Basically what the title says this is the code that I've tried but it doesn't work:

```html
<div id="box" onclick="doSmt(var1, bar2)">
```

```js
if (condition){
box.removeEventListener("click" , doSmt)}
```

Comment: is not gonna work becuz you added an onclick to your div, is not an `addEventListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better if you remove the `onclick` event instead of that attempt

```js
//onclick function
function doSmt(){
   console.log("something");
}

//remove onclick event, this will be inside your if condition
document.getElementById('box').removeAttribute("onclick");
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="doSmt()"> div</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I was trying to get this done in Angular without using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

What what I read at MDN for [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal) you can't remove an event listener that is part of the HTML attribute. So there's two options:

Add the event listener on page load

```
onClickHandler = () => doSmt(var1, var2);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
});

// and later
if (condition) {
document.getElementById('box').removeEventListener('click', onClickHandler)
```

Or if you can't modify the HTML you could modify `doSMT` to watch for a disabled bit.

```
let disableBox = false;

function doSmt() {
  if (disableBox) return;
  // ...
}

if (condition) {
  disableBox = true;
}
```

Or

it can be removed by first accessing the element and then setting the attribute to null

```
<div id="myDiv" onclick="handleClick()">Click me</div>

<script>
  function handleClick() {
    alert("Div was clicked!");
  }

  // Remove the onclick event from the div
  const div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  div.onclick = null;
</script>
```